# iPhone not crashing, no leaks in instruments, is the application ready for upload?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with uploading applications.

At the moment we have an application without any leaks, and how hard we even try to create a crash, in both the simulator and the actual device it just wont let us crash it.

Now we're curious if there are any other developers out there that has been in the same situation and sent their applications to the app store and what the actual outcome was. As we're very cautious and dont want to waste our company's resources we'd like to get as much feedback as possible and cover everything before submitting to the app store.

Please feel free to share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your app conformant to the apple's guidelines? If yes you are good to go. You can even ask for a expedited review in case you have a PR activity planned etc. Don't use private APIs.

Comment: What is a expedited review per definition? I've never heard of it at all :$

Comment: Review process usually takes a long time. Expedited reviews take short time. You can check on the apple site for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure you don't use any undocumented API's immediate fail.
2. Follow the Apple criteria and make sure your app fits their restrictions....

Check my post [App Store Approval](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/06/apple-app-store-approval-process-explained/) which contains a link to the criteria....

Good work having a thoroughly tested app and I admire your desire to ensure your submission is pain-free. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If it does want you want, and you are happy with the amount of testing you've put in it..and it follows Apple's app store guidelines, I'd say its ready for the app store. Quite a large number of apps have huge glaring bugs, so if yours never crashes (doubt this), you are one of the very few.

Also, the process only takes about a week, so I wouldn't say its the end of the world if it somehow gets rejected or you find a bug later.

Comment: Only takes a week at the moment, but this fluctuates depending on quantity of submissions, time of year etc etc ;)

Comment: I've never had an app take longer than 12 days I think. (in 2 years of submitting)

Comment: The Times iPad app, 15 days. The Sun iPad app, 3 days. Lucozade FitCoach app, 30 days. Locassa (my original app) - 9 days, Warner Music App - 19 days. As I said, variable.

Comment: Don't forget Google Voice. About a year!

Comment: Ahhhh indeed, anything that imposes on Apples products and services sits in a dusty box somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ad hoc build and send the application to some iPhone users and ask them for feedback on application. And if app crashes just get the application logs from itunes.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from running a [private beta](https://testflightapp.com/) or adding a [crash reporter](http://quincykit.net/index.html), there isn't much more to do than checking the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) and send your first version.

One issue I ran into is that the plural of a word counts as a whole different keyword. Example, looking up `snippet` won't return applications tagged `snippets` so be sure to include both of them.